# tcl/tk, combine two conditions into one statement

Tags: tcl

I want to combine two conditions in one if statement and avoid using elseif. Right now I have something like this:

```
if { [getmass] < 22 || [getmass] > 23 } {
  dropatom ;
  continue
}
```

I want to make two conditions where [getmass] would be in two different ranges, around 22 and around 35. Is it possible to combine it in one statement under if?

Essentially I want roughly something like [getmass] != 22 || [getmass] != 35, but the actual numbers are not exact integers, they are 22.989... and 35.453... hence I used 22 and 23 for the first condition and 35 and 36 for the second. But I wonder if there is a way to combine it into one short statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements aren't exactly clear, but I'd start with something like this:

```
proc between {value min max} {
    expr {$min <= $value && $value <= $max}
}

set mass [getmass]
if {[between $mass 22 23] || [between $mass 35 36]} {
    puts "I don't like this value: $mass"
} else {
    puts "this is OK: $mass"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<` operator (and its friends) are strictly binary operators. However, you can use the command variants (in the `tcl::mathop` namespace) instead, as that *does* allow chaining. In this case, using the `tcl::mathop::<=` to determine if the value *is* in the range (with the `else` clause covering the case when it isn't):

```
if {[tcl::mathop::<= 22 [getmass] 23]} {
    # puts "the mass is in the range we like"
} else {
    dropatom
    continue
}
```